# How to include jquery in the footer - when using $(document).ready in header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, include

Best practice says : Include all of your javascript in the footer. For faster page load.

Agreed.. but how do you do it to your `jquery` include, when you have all `$` statements all through your body html in a legacy codebase ?

OR

`$(document).ready` in the `head` ?

**Update**
Does that mean - one should always add in-page javascript in the footer of the page after rudimentary includes like `jquery` ?

Comment: Write or Execute your scripts after you include Jquery lib.

Comment: to answer your update, yes: if you're going to run jquery, the script using jquery needs to be after including jquery.

Comment: `Best practice says : Include all of your javascript in the footer. For faster page load.` While true, I disagree with this sentiment, especially since jQuery is so popular and often browser-cached.  Custom scripts may come later, but certainly something that does validation should not be performed last.

Comment: Why all the hate for this question? There isn't a good answer other than "change your HTML or don't move jQuery" but it's valid question.

Comment: @TimMedora: I didn't downvote it, but I can see why others may have.  For this to work (to call something after it exists), would be a *paradox*.  Otherwise, the best you could hope for would be to use `setTimeout` to call code later, which may require to wrap it in an `eval`.  Regardless, it's not advised, and so this doesn't seem like it's a real question.

Comment: @vol7ron - agreed that it's not the greatest question, but as Plynx's answer shows there are some nuances to be considered so it isn't completely black & white. Perhaps a better question would be to show specific code and ask for guidance in removing the head/inline dependencies (e.g. unobtrusive data-* attributes). Regardless, it always intrigues me what gets upvoted/downvoted.

Comment: SO also has guidelines for what's a valid question and many times its not what you'd expect.  Yes the rating system has flaws, but there's not really a better way, since its community driven.

Comment: I have no problem in getting voted down as long as I am able to contribute something. 5 point answer on a -3 question is remarkable in itself. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Everything that uses jQuery has to be included after jQuery is included, which probably means in this case you'll have to leave jQuery in the header. If you are worried about performance, you could include jQuery off a CDN, such as Google: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Comment: Therefore, I can assume that the verdict is "Practically one has to include jquery in the header." Since jQuery is wildly used in the whole document as raw javascript. (Unless intentionally maintained)

Answer (score 3):

JQuery must be included before:

- Plugins extend JQuery
- Calls to immediately executed JQuery functions, e.g. `$(...)` for `document.ready`
- Using JQuery to bind events

JQuery does not need to be included before (although it still needs be included after)

- References to JQuery in unbound or late-bound events
- JQuery selectors in dynamically created elements
- HTML events that are deferred but use JQuery in their handlers

In these cases, the JQuery object won't be evaluated until after its definition, even if it appears earlier.

In your case, however, with legacy code in HTML, it's probably better just to leave it in the header to be safe.